# Copying support files using Autotools

Tags: autotools, automake

Using Autotools is there a way to copy regular text files from my test directory into a build/test directory?

My **test** directory looks like this:

```
Makefile.am
test/testfile.c
test/a.txt
test/b.txt
```

The **Makefile.am** defines **testfile_SOURCES**, **check_PROGRAMS**, and **TESTS**.

My workflow is this:

```
mkdir build
cd build
../configure
make test
```

When I run **make test**, the **build/test** directory is created, but only the **c** executable is copied to it, not the text files. I've tried various methods of copying the text files but nothing works, such as using **$(builddir)**, **$(top_builddir)**, and others.

Comment: The test executable is not *copied* to the build directory.  It is created (only) there in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

> Using Autotools is there a way to copy regular text files from my test directory into a build/test directory?

You should be able to define custom rules for that in your `Makefile.am`, something like this if your project uses recursive `make`:

**test/Makefile.am**

```
$(builddir)/a.txt: $(srcdir)/a.txt
        cp $< $@

$(builddir)/b.txt: $(srcdir)/b.txt
        cp $< $@
```

You would then want to add `$(builddir)/a.txt` and `$(builddir)/b.txt` as prerequisites of some relevant target.  One possibility would be the extension point `all-local`:

```
all-local: $(builddir)/a.txt $(builddir)/b.txt
```

Note that the explicit `$(builddir)` and `$(srcdir)` references are obligatory.

---

Honestly, though, you are probably better off constructing your tests to accept the needed filenames on their command lines, or else to `export srcdir` to enable the tests to read `srcdir` from their environment and use that to locate the data files.